# How much cost one can save if he integrate Cloudflare with Amazon S3 for Video Streaming backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, cloudflare

We are developing a video streaming site

For that we want to use Amazon S3 storage

Since S3 data transfer fees are very high , we decided to integrate S3 with Cloudflare

But it's difficult to calculate cost reduction % . Please help us about how much cost will be saved is we use Cloudflare.

Here is our use case

100 Videos uploaded via S3 Api .. Each having size of 500 MB.(Region LONDON)

```
=> So 100 x 500 = ~ 5GB storage used
```

each and every video requested (GET) 1000 times

```
=> 100 * 1000 = 1,00,000 GET requests
```

each and every video viewed 1000 times

```
=> So (500 x 1000) x 100 = ~ 5 TB bandwidth used
```

---

[image]

> So the Total cost without Cloudflare is $450

**If we use Cloudflare how much % we able to save ?**

Comment: Cloudflare does not belongs to AWS, so there are "cache" transfer cost from S3 to Cloudflare.    Then you just add up the service price of cloudflare 
https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/maxcdn-vs-cloudflare-vs-cloudfront-vs-akamai-edge-vs-fastly/

Comment: BTW, cloudflare also provide differen pricing scheme, 
https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-stream/